# Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /public/uploads/images every time a new post is created

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I am using Laravel 5.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx. Every time when I create a new post the image is stored in `/pubic/uploads/images/IDofPost/imagename.png`

I am using `BKWLD/croppa: Image thumbnail` to optimize the images, however every time a new post is creted a new crop is created as well and I get an error `failed to open stream: Permission denied`.

Until recently I was able to solve my problems with the following command `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/`

Now I have a problem, due to the volume of the files when I run this command I get an error 419 when trying to enter the admin dashboard and if I don't reboot the server I cannot log in. My scheduled commands stop working etc.

How can I make the permissions in /public/uploads permanent for every new file, directory etc?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assign user to directory, try to give read/write permission to `public/uploads` directory. Below is the command to give read/write permission to that directory:-

```
sudo chmod 777 -R public/uploads
```

I think that may help to solve your problem.

Comment: It is the same when a new post is created. I think the new folder is not giving the permissions for the new crop.